# How do I get the commit id of the head of master in git?

Tags: git

I want to display the git commit id (i.e. SHA) of the head of master on my website as an identifier.

How can I pull this information from git?

Answer (score 135):

This command will get you the latest commit's SHA-1

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: +1: I think this "plumbing" approach is better for a scripting-based solution as required by the OP, rather than my "porcelain" approach that I suggest below (i.e., "`git log ...`").

Comment: How to get the latest commit's SHA-1 on **master** branch

Comment: *[andy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1889327/andy)*: `git rev-parse master` will get you the result.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi this works in local git repo, what should be used in a repo which is cloned from remote server like github

Comment: *[Kasun Siyambalapitiya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5105305/kasun-siyambalapitiya)*: This should work on any Git repository. You could use `git rev-parse master` or `git rev-parse origin/master` or any other reference name you want the commit ID of.

Answer (score 41):

Instead of the HEAD SHA1, I would rather go with **[`git describe`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html)**, as a more readable way to get a "build id". For instance:

```
git describe --abbrev=4 HEAD
```

---

If you don't care about tags, and considering that `git describe` is a **[porcelain command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)**, which shouldn't be used in a script, then, yes, `git rev-parse` (a **[plumbing command](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing)**) is more appropriate.

But again, if you are to display a SHA1 on your website as an id, I would go with:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

(In order to display only the first 7 digits of the SHA1)

---

`git rev-parse HEAD` (meaning the all 40 digits) is still useful, when you want to check if what you just deployed is indeed what `HEAD` refers to.
See for instance this [deployment script](https://github.com/freenet/scripts/blob/master/deploy-website):

It first triggers an update:

```sh
#If requested, perform update before gathering information from repos.
if $update; then
    echo "Updating fred-official."
    cd "$fredDir"
    git_update
    if ! [[ "$forceFredID" = "" ]]
    then
        checkGitID "$forceFredID"
    fi
    echo "Updating website repo."
    cd "$websiteDir"
    git_update
    if ! [[ "$forceWebsiteID" = "" ]]
    then
        checkGitID "$forceWebsiteID"
    fi
    cd "$startingDir"
fi
```

The update itself refreshes the website content:

```sh
# Discard any local changes, update remote branches and tags, and
# check out to the latest master branch.
git_update() {
    #To update tags and branches.
    git remote update
    git clean -dfx
    git reset --hard origin/master
}
```

And then it uses `git rev-parse HEAD` to check what just has been checked out:

```sh
function checkGitID {
    checkID=$1
    echo Checking git ID is "$checkID"
    if ! git checkout "$checkID"
    then
        echo Failed to checkout "$checkID"
        exit 4
    fi
    if ! actualID=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
    then
        echo Failed to verify "$checkID"
        git checkout master
        exit 5
    fi
    if ! [[ "$actualID" = "$checkID" ]]
    then
        echo Git verification failed, something very bad is happening
        exit 6
    fi
    echo Git ID verified: "$checkID"
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The following command will return the SHA-1 of HEAD:

```
git log -1 --pretty="%H"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just *slightly* less elegant:

`git log | head -1 | sed s/'commit '//`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
git describe --always --dirty


   --dirty[=<mark>], --broken[=<mark>]
       Describe the state of the working tree. When the working tree matches HEAD, the output is the same
       as "git describe HEAD". If the working tree has local modification "-dirty" is appended to it. If a
       repository is corrupt and Git cannot determine if there is local modification, Git will error out,
       unless ‘--broken’ is given, which appends the suffix "-broken" instead.

   --all
       Instead of using only the annotated tags, use any ref found in refs/ namespace. This option enables
       matching any known branch, remote-tracking branch, or lightweight tag.
```