# Qt Creator: Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, c, qt

I've been struggling for a while with an error in Qt:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _git_repository_open referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

This is obviously a linking error, but I haven't been able to figure out what is causing this. This is all being compiled on Windows, and the library that I'm targeting is libgit2.

I compiled libgit2 using MVSC2010 (which I'm also using for my Qt builds), and then added the external library to my Qt project. The includes are being acknowledged without issue, but the library isn't being linked properly. Since libgit2 is a C library, I've tried included the library in an extern block (and also without the exern block) to no avail:

```
extern "C" {
    #include  <git2.h>
}
```

Also, the function **is** in the lib file:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS git2.lib
...
_git_repository_open@8
...
```

The relevant lines which are throwing an error (the first one works if on its own, since it is defined in the git header, but the second line fails upon linking):

```
git_repository *repo;
git_repository_open(&repo, "/opt/libgit2-test/.git");
```

The relevant qt.pro file lines:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libgit2/lib/ -lgit2
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libgit2/lib/ -lgit2d
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libgit2/lib/ -lgit2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libgit2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libgit2/include
```

Comment: `#include` includes headers, it does not link to libraries. Did you set up your project to actually link against the library? Also, it's unlikely that you need an `extern "C"` block. Headers these days are aware of C++ and you shouldn't try to do this manually. In the libgit2 headers, if you examine them, you will see `#ifdef __cplusplus` guards. So you should remove the `extern "C"` block from your code.

Comment: Nikos, thanks for the reply. I did add the library and the headers to the project file, and if I rename any of the LIBS definitions, it says that it can't find either the lib or the .h file, so it seems like it is finding both of those files properly. Removing extern didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you remove the `extern "C"` block? You shouldn't use one for libgit2.

Comment: Also, please show us the line of code where you call git_repository_open().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you ran across this problem:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/741

You can try the suggestion from here:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/749#issuecomment-6434565

> When building on Windows with the MSVC tool chain, the default build
>   uses the __stdcall convention. However this is not reflected in the
>   header files, so you have to use the /Gz compiler option in your own
>   build as well for being able to successfully link with a libgit2 built
>   that way. If this is not possible or not desirable, set the
>   -DSTDCALL=OFF option when doing the initial cmake.

Comment: I just want to let you know, you are an amazing human being. That was exactly the problem. I'm just starting on learning Qt, so I figured it on that end, but that fixed it perfectly. Thanks again for your help.