# How to get files from multiple commits while running git push in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

`GitLab` run pipeline on git push. While running this pipeline I would like get list of files which are going to be pushed from all commits if there are multiple commits happend.

I am trying to get using this command

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}` but this is giving only recent commit only. If there are more than one commit happend in the branch it is giving only last commit details. I would like to get all files which are committed during that push.

When `git` is able to find all the files from multiple commits which it needs to push , how can not we?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315024/git-list-changed-files-in-several-commits

Comment: I do not know the `pattern` here becuase I might not be the person who is going to commit.

Comment: ok, so this is what I understand, you want to see all files in which changes are made over multiple commits, am I right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git list changed files in several commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315024/git-list-changed-files-in-several-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve my issue.

`git whatchanged --name-only --pretty="" origin..HEAD`

**UPDATE:**
   Above command also includes changes made to master through other branch.
Let's say some one else pushed code changes to master and you did not pull them then when you run the above command, it shows those changes as diff in your current  branch.

I think `whatchanged` is deprectated you can replace it with `log`

If you want to view changes only from your current branch , you can use this
`git diff master... --name-only` or `git diff --name-only master...<branch_name>`

Comment: yeah, that was another good solution, didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

to view file changes between a given commit and your current commit use -

`git diff --name-only <starting SHA> HEAD`

and on being more general to your problem, to check which files changed between two commits do -

`git diff --name-only <commit1> <commit2>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the above commands, How can I find <starting SHA> ?       I do not have any idea about the current branch. I am like a third person who wants to check files which are going to be pushed and run some script on those files.

Comment: <starting SHA> means hash code of respective commit from which you want to view files.

Comment: His question is how to know what the last commit was since the last push.