# How many commands does Git have?

Tags: git

How many commands does Git have ? In particular :

- How many high level commands ?
- How many total commands, including the very low level commands such as git-read-tree` ?

*Optional : How many average flags by command ?*

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of RTFM?

Comment: Because one can extend git with own plugins quite easy: Infinite :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git help -a
```

would list *all* the commands, but without distinction between [porcelain and plumbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git/6978402#6978402) commands.
That would be 152 for a git 1.7.11.3

Comment: 2019 Update: There are 135 git subcommands in git 2.20.1

Comment: @kangalioo `C:\>git version`: `git version 2.20.1.windows.1` and: `C:\>git help -a|grep "^  "|wc -l`: 141.

Comment: I do have exactly 135 subcommands (not counting the external `clang-format`. I'm on Linux though, might be different between OSes