# Is there a way to ignore an exact change with Git?

Tags: git

I am working with an application where I need to change a string to point to a local URL rather than the production URL. Occasionally, I forget the change and run `git commit --all`, which makes for a kind of cluttered git history.

Is there a way to exclude a certain change from all `git add`s? I am aware of `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, but since work is being done in the same file as the string, this wouldn't work.

Would my best option be to move the string out to some sort of "variables" or "environment" file and run the aforementioned command on it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use filters here as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954399/520162

You'd set up a `clean` filter that throws away your single change.

I'm changing paths in VisualStudio files in order to build on a ramdisk while the checked in files should build on a path relative to the sources.