# Imagick complains when I don't set an optional height parameter for sampleImage or resizeImage

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

When I use either resizeImage or sampleImage, I get errors indicating I'm not supplying enough parameters, like so...

```
Warning: Imagick::sampleimage() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
```

In fact, I am only supplying the first parameter because I want to set the width, and not the height, to preserve the aspect ratio...

```
$subImage->resizeImage($w);
```

The code works, and I believe all parameters should be optional except the first one, so why is there an error and how do I eliminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Imagick::sampleImage` you would need to calculate the finial height.

```php
 // new height = original height / original width * new width
 $h = $subImage->getImageHeight() / $subImage->getImageWidth() * $w
 $subImage->sampleimage($w, $h);
```

> I believe all parameters should be optional

Remember the `Imagick` library binds ImageMagick's C-API, and some of the inherited [porcelain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976506/438117) of CLI-API does not carry over directly. Your application *must* do the additional calculations, or you'll experience undefined behavior. Handling aspect rations, quantum colors, degrees, and percentage values are good examples of what your responsible for.