# Why does "git submodule add ..." write to stderr rather than stdout?

Tags: git, shell, stdout, stderr

The message

```
Cloning into 'sub-mod'...
done.
```

after a `git submodule add...` command is written to *stderr*. I expected the message to be written to *stdout* since I don't think it indicates something went wrong with the command.

I can reproduce this with the following sequence of commands:

```
rm   -rf /tmp/repo /tmp/module
mkdir    /tmp/repo /tmp/module

cd /tmp/module

git init  > /dev/null
echo "foo" > foo;
git add foo > /dev/null
git commit . -m "+ foo" > /dev/null


cd /tmp/repo

git init > /dev/null
git submodule add /tmp/module/ sub-mod 1> /dev/null
```

If I change the redirection in the last command to `... 2> /dev/null`, nothing is printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not limited to submodules, as [noted here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/RFC-PATCH-0-5-WAS-Submodule-Groups-Labels-and-submodule-autoInitialize-tt7646332.html#a7646333):

> The registration of the submodule will be reported to **stderr, as that is
> consistent with the rest of progress reporting within Git**.
>
> This helps us in a later patch when we want to reuse the
> [`init_submodule` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f66975deb8402131fbf7c14330d0c7cdebaeaa2/builtin/submodule--helper.c#L308) in [`update_clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f66975deb8402131fbf7c14330d0c7cdebaeaa2/builtin/submodule--helper.c#L757) whose stdout will be piped
> to shell which reads parameters off stdout in a very specific way.

You can see it also in [this recent patch](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/RFC-PATCHv4-0-7-Git-submodule-labels-tt7651205.html#a7651209):

> Reroute the output of stdout to **stderr as it is just informative
> messages, not to be consumed by machines**.
>
> We want to init submodules from the helper for `submodule update`
> in a later patch and the stdout output of said helper is consumed
> by the parts of `submodule update` which are still written in shell.
>
> So we have to be careful which messages are on stdout.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), coding guideline document has been updated to clarify what goes to standard error in our system.

See [commit e258eb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e258eb4800e30da2adbdb2df8d8d8c19d9b443e4) (02 Dec 2021) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 212962d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/212962deba57df0207743eda93f7b017bedd2cf6), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`CodingGuidelines`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e258eb4800e30da2adbdb2df8d8d8c19d9b443e4): document which output goes to stdout vs. stderr
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>

> It has long been practice on this project for a command to emit its primary output to stdout so that it can be captured to a file or sent down a pipe, and to emit "chatty" messages (such as those reporting progress) to stderr so that they don't interfere with the primary output.
> However, this practice is not necessarily universal; another common practice is to send only error messages to stderr, and all other messages to stdout.
> Therefore, help newcomers out by documenting how stdout and stderr are used on this project.

`CodingGuidelines` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e258eb4800e30da2adbdb2df8d8d8c19d9b443e4/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L502-L528):

> ### Program Output
>
> We make a distinction between a Git command's primary output and
> output which is merely chatty feedback (for instance, status
> messages, running transcript, or progress display), as well as error
> messages. Roughly speaking, a Git command's primary output is that
> which one might want to capture to a file or send down a pipe; its
> chatty output should not interfere with these use-cases.
>
> As such, primary output should be sent to the standard output stream
> (stdout), and chatty output should be sent to the standard error
> stream (stderr). Examples of commands which produce primary output
> include `git log`, `git show`, and `git branch --list` which generate
> output on the stdout stream.
>
> Not all Git commands have primary output; this is often true of
> commands whose main function is to perform an action. Some action
> commands are silent, whereas others are chatty. An example of a
> chatty action commands is `git clone` with its "Cloning into
> ''..." and "Checking connectivity..." status messages which it
> sends to the stderr stream.
>
> Error messages from Git commands should always be sent to the stderr
> stream.

Comment: Surprised they didn't think to add a flag for machine-readable output...

Comment: @aleclarson machine-readable output is the default in Git, and goes to stdout. Anything else goes to stderr.

Comment: Maybe, but I would prefer the approach of `git status` with its `--porcelain` flag, instead of abusing stderr. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @aleclarson I understand. I present the `--porcelain` option in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309.

Comment: Perhaps a special character for identifying output that should not be machine-read would be better than abusing stderr.