# PowerShell Capture Git Output

Tags: git, powershell, logging

#### Problem

I am running some git commands through PowerShell but I am having issues capturing the output.

Many of the ways I have looked into have failed to capture any output at all until I tried using `Out-File` . Unfortunately, despite how well this has been working for me, I have found that something is going wrong with the `git push` command that is preventing me from capturing the output...

My code looks as follows:

```
git add . | Out-File $logFilePath -Append
git status . | Out-File $logFilePath -Append
git commit -m "Some Relevant update message" | Out-File $logFilePath -Append
git push origin $branchname | Out-File $logFilePath -Append
```

When I look at the log files, it shows everything but the output of the `git push`. So in troubleshooting this, I removed the `| Out-File` from the line and noticed that even the output window was not showing the output of the `git push` anymore. It was only when I completely removed the `Out-File` from all of the git commands that I was able to get the output to display as expected again. Unfortunately, this put me back at square one.

#### Question

Does anyone know how to best capture the output of git commands using PowerShell, or can point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771637/6309), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309), Git command output are done on stderr, not stdout.

So in your case, you need to pipe stderr.
See "[Redirection of standard and error output appending to the same log-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8938256/6309)" for instance.

Note: **[with Git 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232450/6309)** (Q1 2018), you can try and set first

```
 set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
```

Then stderr should be redirected to stdout.

In "[PowerShell - Capturing STDERR Output for Git Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402329/6309)", the [OP Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8371580/brandon) points out to the [`--porcelain` option of (for instance)  git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---porcelain):

```
& git status --porcelain >> $logFilePath
& git push --porcelain >> $logFilePath
```

It allows to convert the outputs into a machine readable format and pipe them to the output.

Comment: Thank you. These have all been very informative. I am going to play around with this for a bit to be sure that I have all the information I need before closing this out. Thank you again

Comment: I don't suppose you could help me just one step further? I have `ErrorActionPreference` set to `Stop` and every attempt I have made to capture this data (apart from temporarily changing the `ErrorActionPreference` ) has led to code failure whenever an `stderr` is encountered... Is there an easy way to ensure the code doesn't fail for certain `stderr` output (warnings, successful pushes, etc), yet still fail when a true critical error is encountered?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I will have a look tomorrow, but you might add a new question more targeted to that specific issue.

Comment: Thanks anyways, but I shall definitely go ahead and setup a new question

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to write "normal" PowerShell code that returns the output of git, you can override the command with a function that calls the command.  This is because in PowerShell, command are resolved in the order:

- Alias
- Function
- Cmdlet
- ExternalScript
- Application (what git.exe is)

So you can write a *very* trivial function to override git (the application).

```
function git() {
    # Call git with splatting
    & (Get-Command git -commandType Application) @args 2>&1
}
```

This type of function is sometimes called a "v1" or "simple" function (because functions with `[CmdletBinding()]` or `[Parameter()]` were a v2 addition originally called "advanced functions".

These functions do not have standard PowerShell parameters, like `-ErrorAction`, but they *will* call down to git seamlessly and return a list of results.

Then you can do:

```
$gitOutput = git status
```

Of course you still have to parse the results.

If you'd like to skip the pain of parsing git output, I wrote a PowerShell module that uses this trick and allows for extensible conversion of any git command into objects.

It's called [ugit](https://github.com/StartAutomating/ugit).

With ugit, for instance, you can say:

```
# get all untracked files
git status | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Untracked

# get all branches that are not the current branch or named 'main' or 'master'
git branch |
    Where-Object -Not IsCurrentBranch |
    Where-Object -Name -NotIn main, master
```