# PowerShell - Capturing STDERR Output for Git Commands

Tags: git, powershell, logging, error-handling, stderr

### Problem

I am trying to capture the `STDERR` outputs into a log file; however, I have been encountering some serious inconsistent issues that are making my task harder.

First off, I have my `ErrorActionPreference` to 'Stop', which is probably part of the problems I am enduring.

Second, I have tried two variants for EACH git command in my code displayed below:

#### Variant 01

```
& git add $path2File 2>&1 | Out-File "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git commit -m "Some logical update message" 2>&1 | Out-File "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git status 2>&1 | Out-File "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git push 2>&1 | Out-File "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
```

#### Variant 02

```
& git add $path2File 2>&1 >> "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git commit -m "Some Logical update message" 2>&1 >> "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git status 2>&1 >> "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
& git push 2>&1 >> "$LogPath\$tmpLogName" -Append
```

There were several other variants in which I mixed up which command used which variant depending upon common issues I had encountered.

The primary issues I have been encountering are:

1) whenever an `STDERR` output is encountered, it is treated as a terminating error, regardless of the message.

2) My attempts to create custom `Try/Catch` statements have failed due to a number of reasons. Exit Codes were not always the same for successful `STDERR` messages. Couldn't use plain text matches for anything beyond warnings due to messages not always using the same or similar messages.

NOTE: I am trying to do this without changing the `ErrorActionPreference` unless absolutely necessary.

### Question

Does anyone know how to handle logging the `STDERR` messages for git commands so that it always logs the responses without throwing a terminating error except for true critical errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I get to answer my own question this time around.

Using [git-scm.com/docs](https://git-scm.com/docs) I was able to learn that some of the git commands had a `--porcelain` option which allows me to convert the outputs into a machine readable format and pipe them to the output. Then, using a combination of `>>` and `*>>` depending on the command, I came up with the following:

```
& git checkout --track $branch >> $logFilePath

# some set of actions

& git add . *>> $logFilePath
& git commit -m "some automated update message" *>> $logFilePath
& git status --porcelain >> $logFilePath
& git push --porcelain >> $logFilePath
```

This allowed me to get the information I wanted to record without the false terminating errors, and If I needed to mask anything (IP Address, PI, etc), I could do so before it ever gets logged or displayed.

If there is no need to do so, using `Tee-Object` has also been extremely helpful to achieve the desired results while still triggering any errors appropriately rather than just generating a terminating error simply because it came from STDERR

Answer (score 0):

You can try using -q to suppress the git output. It should still error, if there is an actual git error.

I think you may also be able to run it in just Powershell, not the ISE and it should work properly

Comment: Unfortunately, no this is not what I want. I am not trying to suppress the messages or silently bypass them. I need these messages to display and to be able to capture them.

Comment: Can you give this a go and see if it suits your purpose?

try{invoke-expression "git command -q"}catch{$_}; From what I can tell, invoke-expression with the -q will suppress normal output and only catch errors, which are then caught in the try/catch.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your attempt, but there is a huge problem with this approach.  Using `-q` or `-quiet` is suppressing the output, which is detrimental to my goal. Not only must I get the errors to catch/trigger, but I need to display all output (info, warning, errors, etc) and log that output as well. Which is why `-q` won't work for me.