# Git push doesn't exit

Tags: git

I'm messing around with git for the first time on my PC. I have one repository in `D:\MyProjectA\`, and a bare clone of the repository in `D:\MyProjectB\`. Then I setup the bare clone to be `origin` by running `remote add origin D:\MyProjectB`.

Now I've made some changes to MyProjectA and want to push them back to origin. When I run `git push origin master` in Powershell, I see the following output, but the script *doesn't exit*. I have to Ctrl-C to close. What's going on?

```
PS D:\MyProjectA> git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes | 290.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to check, would the same command work with no pager?

```
git --no-pager push origin master
```

If so, type:

```
git config --global core.pager more.com
```

Also, [with Git 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309) (recently released), try:

```
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = "2>&1"
```

And see if that helps.

Finally, setting various [`GIT_TRACE` variables](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bac65a2be598811d944c846bdf61580f5c1af927/Documentation/git.txt#L1006-L1012) can help debug the command.

The [OP cbp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21966/cbp) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364238/git-push-doesnt-exit/48364347?noredirect=1#comment83715915_48364347):

> I have just had success in `CMD` (not Powershell) using `GIT_TRACE`.
>   And what I observed is that it hung for a long time running `git pack-objects`.  Eventually it finished and exited.
>   Subsequently, running `git push` appears to be much faster.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately the behaviour is the same with --no-pager. Will try upgrading Git and see if redirecting STDERR helps.

Comment: I tried `set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR="2>&1"` (after upgrading to 2.16), but the behaviour is the same unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm I don't see any trace messages... but I'm not sure if the tracing is working as I can't see any tracing for any commands I run. I tried both `set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR="2>&1"` and `set GIT_TRACE=1` but am seeing no observable difference in output for any commands.

Comment: @cbp Maybe a stderr issue. I suppose the push alone works well when done from a simple CMD?

Comment: No it exhibits the same behaviour in CMD as in Powershell - and no evidence of anything going to STDERR.

Comment: @cbp Can you try again, in a CMD, after setting a simplified PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826648/6309

Comment: Ahh... I have just had success in CMD (not Powershell) using GIT_TRACE. And what I observed is that it hung for a long time running `git pack-objects`. _Eventually_ it finished and exited. Subsequently, running `git push` appears to be much faster. I guess that explains it!

Comment: I notice your helping me on another similar, but different question about git plus Dropbox (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364494/cant-push-to-git-repository-in-dropbox-under-boxcryptor). Unfortunately that question is still unresolved. Appreciated your help :)

Comment: @cbp Great!  I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Now, for that other question...