# Can't push to Git repository in Dropbox under BoxCryptor

Tags: git

Firstly, I have a repository on my machine, outside of DropBox. Next, I have cloned the repository (bare) and into a folder inside DropBox, which is being encrypted by BoxCryptor.

As per the following commands, both appear to be accessible and treated as git repositories correctly:

```
PS D:\MyProject> git remote -v
origin  X:\Dropbox (Personal)\MyProject.git\" (fetch)
origin  X:\Dropbox (Personal)\MyProject.git\" (push)

PS D:\MyProject> cd 'X:\Dropbox (Personal)\MyProject.git'
PS X:\Dropbox (Personal)\MyProject.git> git remote -v
origin  D:\MyProject\ (fetch)
origin  D:\MyProject\ (push)
```

However, I'm unable to push from the folder outside DropBox, to the folder inside DropBox:

```
PS D:\MyProject> git push origin master
fatal: 'Dropbox (Personal)\MyProject.git"' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now I know it's not a permission problem - I have write access to the folder. And of course, it *is* a repository, because I can run `git log` inside the folder and see the log.

I suspect it may either have to do with funny stuff going on with BoxCryptor. Or is it because of that weird extra double quote at the end of the origin url (in which case, how do I get rid of it?)?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue - it appears to be that git is buggy in the way it deals with the path, appending the double quote for no reason.

Firstly, I tried editing `.git\config` directly and removing the double quote:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = X:\\Dropbox (Personal)\\MyProject.git\
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

However git became confused about the url:

```
fatal: 'X:\\Dropbox (Personal)\\MyProject.git fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Next, I tried adding a double quote to the start of the line in `.git\config`. But this didn't work either.

I could resolve the issue by creating a symbolic link that didn't have spaces.

Finally I figured it out - git doesn't want the slash at the end of the url! Removing the double quote and the slash fixes the problem:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = X:\\Dropbox (Personal)\\MyProject.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Good catch. +1. I had known about the final '/', I could have told you right away it was not needed.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I didn't think it was important at first

Answer (score 1):

Try and edit your local config to remove the extra double-quotes:

```
cd D:\MyProject
git config --local --edit
```

That might be enough for the push to succeed.

Comment: I removed the quote but it gets confused with the following line in the config file. Obviously it needs the double-quotes to deal with the space in the directory name. Editing the config, I also tried adding another double-quote at the start of the line, but it didn't like that either.

Comment: @cbp Did you try with a unix path: `/D/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/MyProject.git` (without quotes: note the escape on the \( and \) and \ (space))