# Git add --verbose output not captured in Powershell verbose stream

Tags: c#, git, powershell

When I run "git add . --verbose" I get messages showing the files that are being added like this:

```
add 'file1.txt"
add 'file2.txt"
```

But when I run the same git command in C# via PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke(), the verbose messages are not being redirected to Streams.Verbose.  In fact, they are not being redirected to any of the Streams.  What am I missing?  Is there anything wrong with the code?

Here's my code:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += VerboseStream_DataAdded;
ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);

void VerboseStream_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
   // this is never called
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because of the git add command making an output on stderr, instead of stdout.
With Git 2.16+ ([as I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309)), you can try:

```
set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
```

But that might be ignored by a Csharp Git program.

Comment: I checked the link you provided.  It talks about git push --porcelain.  Unfortunately, git add does not have a --porcelain option.  In my C# code, I also check for output to Streams.Error (I assume this is stderr), and no verbose output is redirected there.

Answer (score 1):

From what I grasp about streams in Powershell ([I glanced at this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) ), it looks like a process in Powershell may write to 5 different output streams.

AFAIK, `git` was written with a unix like setup in mind, and is only "aware" of two output streams : stdout and stderr. I didn't look at the code, but I highly doubt `git`'s codebase was adapted to take into account those five streams on Windows.

---

In your Powershell code : try pluging your callback to the `Error` stream or the `Success` stream.

Comment: Actually, in my C# code, I have callbacks for the 5 PowerShell streams.  Only the Error callback gets called.  Perhaps your suspicion that git's codebase was not adapted to take advantage of the 5 streams in Windows is correct.  I hope someone can confirm this.


The discussion of Write-Host in the article you suggested was very helpful.  I suspect that git's verbose output is written using Write-Host and not Write-Verbose.  Again, I hope someone can confirm this.