# Running "Git-Clone" from Powershell giving errors even when it seems to work

Tags: git, powershell-4.0

How do I interpret the errors coming out of this PowerShell script that calls "Git Clone" (actually using GitLab).  And can I clone an empty directory and cause it to work without getting errors?

```
$path1 = "d:\GitPath" 
$path2 = "${path1}\mycompany-mygroup-nealtestautomation01-map"
$gitLabHttp = "http://git.mycompany.com/MyGroup/nealtestscriptaddedproject.git"
$gitLabHttp = "http://git.mycompany.com/MyGroup/mycompany-gwcustomers-nealtestautomation01-map.git" 
rd $path2 
cd $path1
git clone $gitLabHttp --local --verbose
```

Output:

```
git : Cloning into 'mycompany-mygroup-nealtestautomation01210-map'...
At D:\Scripts\GitCloneTest.ps1:7 char:1
+ git clone $gitLabHttp --local --verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Cloning into '...mation01-map'...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
warning: --local is ignored
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

In the larger script where I want to use this code, I include this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"  #Special Poweshell Syntax to Stop on First Error
```

so that it stops on the first error.

Even when I run it on a non-empty project, I see red and errors similar to above (took the --local and --verbose off this run):

```
git : Cloning into 'xxx.yyy.CanInvToOutZZZ210.Map'...
At D:\Scripts\GitCloneTest2.ps1:5 char:1
+ git clone $gitLabHttp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Cloning into 'E...Intl210.Map'...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

If I run from windows command prompt, it runs nicely with some stats:

```
D:\GitGWCustomerMaps\Test2>git clone myrealurlhidden 
Cloning into 'XXX.YYY.CanInvToOutZZZZ210.Map'...
remote: Counting objects: 29, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (29/29), done.
```

Comment: I'm experimenting with the --Quiet flag, which might work, but not sure why I'm getting any errors that need to be suppressed with that flag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I mention in "[PowerShell Capture Git Output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309)", since a Git command can output information message on stderr ([instead of stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309)), try (with Gti 2.16+)

```
set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
```

(or adapt that variable setting to your script)

That might avoid your script to stop on the first "error", which is actually not an error

The [OP NealWalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160245/nealwalters) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372601/running-git-clone-from-powershell-giving-errors-even-when-it-seems-to-work/54624579#comment96210665_54624579):

> I ended up using the wrapper function **`Invoke-Git`** from "[Git clone: Redirect stderr to stdout but keep errors being written to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232450/6309)"

Comment: This is an environmental variable?  From Win command prompt I tried: set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1, then typed in set and didn't see the variable created.  I also tried in Powershell, it says: + set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
+                           ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.  My Git Version: 2.16.1.windows.1

Comment: @NealWalters Yes it is: mode details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232450/6309 and https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a172e4ac1719a068c76384bd077ee65d915ebea: `GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR="2>&1"`

Comment: I ended up using the wrapper function Invoke-Git from the link above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820975/git-clone-redirect-stderr-to-stdout-but-keep-errors-being-written-to-stderr/47232450#47232450

Comment: @NealWalters Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.