# Git log does not show anything on console

Tags: git, ubuntu, konsole

I am using Kubuntu 16.4. LTS. Recently, I have updated my packages using the following commands:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Since then, the command `git log` does not provide any output.

When using `git log > /tmp/gitlog.txt` however, the file contains the desired output.

How can I get `git log` working back?

Comment: what is you git version?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PAGER` and `set|grep LESS`?

Comment: `echo $PAGER` shows an empty line, `set | grep LESS` shows nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are in a local git repo, and make that you have a least one commit.

Your folder should include `.git/` in it.

> `git log` does not show anything on console, but `git log > /tmp/gitlog.txt` writes commits into the file in the pipe.

It may be a pager issue, which blocks the output on the console, but does not apply when redirecting to a file.
Check with `git --no-pager  log`.

---

The [OP lazyboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564008/lazyboy) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496359/git-log-does-not-show-anything-on-console/50496393#comment88117441_50496393) an issue related to the pager:

> the idea with pager helps me to check my system.
>   Some of startup scripts changed pager in my system and have affect to git.

Comment: `git --no-pager` prints all log-entries to console, How to let `git log` work with pager?

Comment: Nops, I tried only `git --no-pager`. The command prints all entries to console. Not so usefull :(

Comment: @lazyboy Did you try `git --no-pager log 2> /tmp/gitlog.txt` (in case that command uses stderr for its output, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771637/6309)

Comment: The answer does not help me directly to make git work again, but the idea with pager helps me to check my system. Some of startup scripts changed pager in my system and have affect to git.

Comment: @lazyboy Well spotted! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same issue and fixed it by going into my `.gitconfig` file and deleting `diff-highlight` from the `pager` configs:

before (`git log/diff/show` not displaying anything):

```
[pager]
  log = diff-highlight | less
  show = diff-highlight | less
  diff = diff-highlight | less
```

after (everything works)

```
[pager]
  log = less
  show = less
  diff = less
```

no other pager config path setting or command flag work-arounds.