# cloning git repo from python

Tags: python, git, subprocess

src = user/my.git    dest = /home/git_name   ver = 1.1

```
def run
   p = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I am calling this run with the following cmds

```
1.  self.run(['mkdir', '-p', dest])
2.  self.run(['git', 'clone', '--no-checkout',src, dest])
3.  self.run(['cd', dest, ';', 'git', 'checkout', '--detach', ver]])
```

output:
1st run is a success
2nd run to clone gets the error stderr=b"Cloning into ' /home/git_name'...\n
3rd run is a success.

This directory /home/git_name.OLD.1723430 gets created and  I see a .git inside this directory.
I also have a file  /home/git_name which points to the src, basically has a link to the src directory.

Both of these should happen in the same directory and I don't know why there are two and partial results in both.
I am not sure what's wrong

Also,
src = user/my.git/repos/tags/1.1 is the actual location of the tags
when I try to use the entire path git clone says path is not right

Why does this happen?

Comment: Note that `subprocess.run` has `shell=False` as a default, which means you cannot put `cd <path>; <cmd>` in and expect it to work. There are two obvious ways to handle this: use the `cwd=` optional argument *to* `subprocess.run` so that you don't need a `cd <path>`, solving this problem entirely in Python; or use `git -C <path>`, solving this problem with an argument to the Git command you run.

Comment: You could of course add `shell=True`, but [see xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`sh`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh).  Excellent for this kind of stuff.

```
>>> import sh
>>> sh.git.clone(git_repo_url, "destination")
```

If you want to do fancy stuff like changing into a repo and run commands, you also have `cd` available as a context manager:

```
with sh.cd(git_repo):
    # do git commands
```

Also read this note about running [`git` commands](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/contrib.html#contrib-git).

Answer (score 1):

> 2nd run to clone gets the error stderr=b"Cloning into ' /home/git_name'...\n

It is not an error, just the fact human-readable output is [often redirected to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771637/6309).

Note: `/home` is for user accounts. You would usually clone a repository *inside* `/home/me`, not directly in `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this to make it work

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', '--no-checkout', self.src, self.destination],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
b =subprocess.Popen(['git', 'checkout', '--detach', self.ver], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd= self.destination).communicate()[0]
```

Used shell = False(which is the default) & and added cwd to the argument list to make this switch in directory for git to work

Thanks to Everyone who helped!