# How to make that git push origin master dont show output of files in repo

Tags: git

I'm trying that `git push` don't show the output.

I try with `--quiet` option and redirection to `/dev/null` like that:

```
git push origin master &>/dev/null
```

But Git still shows all files of the repo when a make a push like that:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': n0zg
Password for 'https://n0zg@github.com': 
test.html
888.html
9991.html
999.html
index.html
css/
css/stylesheet.css
highlight/
highlight/README.md
highlight/LICENSE
highlight/CHANGES.md
highlight/README.ru.md
highlight/styles/
highlight/styles/ir-black.css
....
```

How can I make that `git push` don't show all files in the repo on the terminal?

Comment: `git push origin master 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309), most of the `git` commands do their output on `stderr`, not `stdout`.

> stderr is just informative messages, not to be consumed by machines.

That means, as commented, that you need to redirect stderr to /dev/null: `2>`

The OP however comments that:

- `&>` should have redirect *both* outputs to `/dev/null`
- > [It] was an error of mine, I didn't see a `tar czvf` that I have in the shell script that was generate the output.

Comment: I tried 2> but that does not work. &> rediect both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @n0z Agreed, but did you try to redirect just stderr? (in case the &> is not well supported in your context)

Comment: @n0z What Git version are you using, on which OS?

Comment: I forget mention that is inside a shell script  in linux :S

Comment: @n0z Still interested ion the Git version. Just in case, would `> /dev/null 2>&` work better?

Comment: Git version is 2.13.2 and SO arch linux

Comment: @n0z "I forget mention that is inside a shell script in linux": would the same `&>` redirection work when executed directly from the command line instead of from a script.

Comment: I have to apologize, was a error of mine, i didn't see a `tar czvf` that i have in the shell script that was generate the output.  T.T

Comment: @n0z Thank you for this feedback: I have included it in the answer, for more visibility (and to help others). I have also included the `&>` syntax.