# Python repo popen could not work in python script but works on the terminal

Tags: python, git

I have a python script which captures repo command.

```
import subprocess

processing(commandforrepo)

def processing(repocmd):
    process = None
    process = subprocess.Popen(repocmd,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
    process.communicate()
```

In the particular command, I am trying to parse a list of repocmd to compare two branches and print out the differences

```
"repo forall $(repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT')\
     -c 'git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline --no-merges \
     --cherry-pick --left-only HEAD...$REPO_RREV'"
```

Attempted to run the script on the terminal but the command did not get executed. However, when this command is issued on the terminal, it produces a list of differences between the two branches.

Any clue as to what is missing?

Comment: i think you forgot to set a variable to the output of Proc.communicate(), what are you expecting will happen? You're piping stdout to your script, and not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: most of the standard output for Git command are done on... stderr.
See [here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309): informative messages are on stderr only.

So make sure to parse stderr, not stdout.