# Git Hooks. How to read variables from user input?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, githooks

I'm trying to create a pre-commit hook. And I want it to interract with user. So, I've found that I can use
`read -p "Enter info: " info`
Or just
`read info`

---

I created a file:
**pre-commit:**

```
#!/bin/sh
read -r input
echo $input
```

It just should read variable and output it. But it doesn't work. I mean it doesn't work as hook. If I run it using terminal with `./.githooks/pre-commit`, everything is okay. But when I use `git commit -am "Hook"`, it echos empty string and doesn't read anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Git version is 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: From the docs: `Hooks can get their arguments via the environment, command-line arguments, and stdin. See the documentation for each hook below for details.`, stdin is not for user input with hooks.

Comment: What about `read -r input < /dev/tty`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/guilherme/9604324), you might need to take into account stderr (used by Git commands, as [for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309))

```
#!/bin/sh
# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2
# enable user input
exec < /dev/tty
```

Example of a script following those lines:

```
consoleregexp='console.log'
# CHECK
if test $(git diff --cached | grep $consoleregexp | wc -l) != 0
then 
  exec git diff --cached | grep -ne $consoleregexp
  read -p "There are some occurrences of console.log at your modification. Are you sure want to continue? (y/n)" yn
  echo $yn | grep ^[Yy]$
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
  then
    exit 0; #THE USER WANTS TO CONTINUE
  else
    exit 1; # THE USER DONT WANT TO CONTINUE SO ROLLBACK
  fi
fi
```