# bash - Unable to save entire output of git clone into a variable

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to save the output of `git clone` into a bash variable. When I do the below, I only get the first line

```
DIR=$(git clone repo_url  >& /dev/stdout)
echo $DIR
```

**Output:**

```
Cloning into [repo_name]...
```

How can I save the entire output of `git clone`?

I've tried this on Ubuntu and MacOS.

**Desired output**

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 57, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
remote: Total 9163 (delta 28), reused 30 (delta 11), pack-reused 9106
Receiving objects: 100% (9163/9163), 14.62 MiB | 44.41 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7014/7014), done.
```

Comment: What exactly are the missing lines? In case it's errors, it could be the case that your solution only captures stdout and not stderr, that's why I ask...

Comment: Just added the desired output. I would like to save all the cloning progress updates

Comment: Just tried `declare -p DIR` and it also just gave the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `--progress` fr the full output.

```
DIR=$(git clone --progress repo_url  >& /dev/stdout)
```

`>&` redirects both stdout and stderr, which is correct considering [`git` commands often outputs information on stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309).