# Why `git pull` doesn't work when executed from within a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitlab

I'm trying to use the `subprocess` module to perform a `git pull` operation in a repository. The problem is that other commands, such as `git status` work fine, but the `git pull` doesn't. No output is generated.

This is where I'm stuck:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output(
  ['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'main']
)
```

When executed, the following error is thrown:

```
[WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I also used the `os.chdir` and `cwd` to change the dir context to the target repository, but it didn't work as expected:

```py
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir(my_repository_dir)

subprocess.check_output(
  ['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'main'],
  cwd=my_repository_dir
)
```

None of the following `subprocess` methods worked: `check_output`, `check_call`, `run` and `Popen`. Either using the `shell` attribute or not.

Furthermore, I reached the GitPython module, but it didn't work either.

My Python script runs on a **Windows Server 2022**, and the installed Python version is `3.6.8`. The `git pull` instruction is evaluated when the exposed `Flask` app handles an incoming HTTP request.

The target dir is a valid Git repository.

I've already included the SSH key on Gitlab, and the account credentials are stored in the *Windows Credentials Manager*.

If `git pull` isn't intended to be invoked from scripts, I'd like to understand the proper way to do this.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Python running as Windows Service: OSError: \[WinError 6\] The handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid)

Comment: @brian DEVNULL is meant to discard any information it receives. So, I think it would omit the error but wouldn't fix the issue.

Comment: That question is about the STDIN handle used by the subprocess. That has no impact on what or how the subprocess writes to STDOUT/STDERR.

Comment: @brian I've come across this question, but even with other special values, such as DEVNULL, PIPE, STDOUT, etc. I couldn't get any relevant results :/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other use of `check_output` with `git` commands in [this library](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aultralytics%2Fyolov3%20check_output&type=code), you can try:

```
result = subprocess.check_output('git pull', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode()
print(result)
```

By redirecting the `stderr` stream to the same output as `stdout`, you will be sure to capture everything.
That matters considering [most git commands outputs information message on `stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that way, and it did work with `git status`, but when I attempt to run a `git pull` instead, nothing happens; neither the following `print` nor the following instructions are executed. The program just gets blocked... Is it possible that the CMD is waiting for such input, or the `git` could not reach the git credentials even after I've added the SSH key to the repository?

Comment: @user299294 It is possible, yes. First, check the remote URL actually used (git remote -v). If it is an HTTPS one, SSH key won't matter. If it is an SSH one, HTTPS credentials won't matter. Second, try a git pull manually (outside your program). Third, make sure your program is running with the same Windows account as the one you are using for a manual test.