# Plumbing equivalent for `git checkout -- .`

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I'm looking for a scripting-suitable plumbing command (or commands) that are equivalent to the high-level porcelain command `git checkout -- .`

My initial thought would be to use `git checkout-index --all --force`, however this does not fully restore the working directory in the case of `core.autocrlf = input`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

rm -rf repo
git init repo
cd repo

git config --local core.autocrlf input

python3 -c 'open("foo", "wb").write(b"1\r\n2\r\n")'
git add foo
python3 -c 'open("foo", "wb").write(b"3\r\n4\r\n")'

git checkout-index --all --force
echo 'I expect this `git status` to have no modifications'
git status
```

This produces the following output:

```
+ rm -rf repo
+ git init repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/repo/.git/
+ cd repo
+ git config --local core.autocrlf input
+ python3 -c 'open("foo", "wb").write(b"1\r\n2\r\n")'
+ git add foo
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in foo.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
+ python3 -c 'open("foo", "wb").write(b"3\r\n4\r\n")'
+ git checkout-index --all --force
+ echo 'I expect this `git status` to have no modifications'
I expect this `git status` to have no modifications
+ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   foo
```

Note that `git checkout -- .` correctly restores the working directory to the contents of the `index`, even in this case.

Comment: I guess you could inspect the source code of `git-checkout` to see how it works and reproduce that behaviour, but what makes `git checkout -- .` itself unsuitable for scripting? It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Chris Generally you want to [avoid porcelain commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/812183) for scripting as they are considered "high level" and do not guarantee a stable api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `git checkout-index`: it doesn't know how to deal with the fact that the work-tree matches the index after all.

If we add `git ls-files --stage --debug`, we see that after the first `git add`, the index contains:

```
100644 1191247b6d9a206f6ba3d8ac79e26d041dd86941 0   foo
  ctime: <ct>
  mtime: <mt>
  dev: <d>  ino: <i>
  uid: <u>  gid: <g>
  size: 6   flags: 0
```

(I have replaced irrelevant variable values with `<...>` here).  Note that the listed size is 6, not 4: this is the size of the work-tree file, which really is 6 bytes long because it contains `\r\n` line endings.

Next, we do:

```
python3 -c 'open("foo", "wb").write(b"3\r\n4\r\n")'
```

which replaces the file, rewriting the existing inode with new time stamps and new contents.  The new contents are 6 bytes long.

Then we do:

```
git checkout-index [arguments]
```

which overwrites the work-tree file with the index contents, just as `git checkout` does.  The file is now 4 bytes long ... but the index still says the file is 6 bytes long.

If we *rename* `foo`, so that `git checkout-index` has to re-create `foo` with a different inode number, we find that the `stat` information in the index is *still* out of date.  In other words, even though `git checkout-index` is re-writing `foo`, it never updates the cached stat information.  So `git status`'s internal index-vs-work-tree diff uses the fast path (compare cached stat data to stat data for actual in-file-system file) and assumes it must be modified.

(Oddly enough, `git update-index --refresh -q` won't touch the cache info either, and I am not sure why not.)

The solution would seem to be to use `git checkout` directly, at least until `git checkout-index` is fixed.

Comment: This confirms my suspicions, thanks.  I've [written the git mailing list about this](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=150152051316004&w=2).