# Programmatically check if HEAD is detached?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I want to know whether I'm in a "HEAD detached" state in a script.

Currently I parse the output of `git status` but I dislike doing so because I've heard that it's a bad practice to parse Git output that's meant for human - I want a program-friendly interface to tell me whether HEAD is detached. I also don't want to manually look into `.git/HEAD` or parse `git description` or `git branch`.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git

Comment: You can try `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD`, if it outputs HEAD, you're in detached mode, if it outputs a branch name, you're on that branch.

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` will give you a branch name if you're on a branch else will give you the detached HEAD hash

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest command is probably:

```
$ git symbolic-ref -q HEAD
```

and check the exit status: 0 means normal; 1 is detached.

From the docs of `git-symbolic-ref`:

```
-q, --quiet
   Do not issue an error message if the <name> is not a symbolic ref
   but a detached HEAD; instead exit with non-zero status silently.
```

Comment: Great solution. I'll just take this one.

Answer (score 9):

Programmatically check requires a wrapper for `Git` protocol.

For example, by [`GitPython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=detach#switching-branches) you're able to find out the repo detached or not `repo.head.is_detached`

Comment: I didn't mention what language I'm programming in. It could be Bash where the only interface is the `git` binary. And that's good - Once you know how to do it in Bash you can do it in any language - by calling `git` binary.

Comment: @iBug `git symbolic-ref HEAD` may help you and just indicate the fatal error by `grep` command.

Answer (score 2):

From git 2.22, you can also use:

```
git branch --show-current
```

This prints nothing when not on a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git branch` to find a detached HEAD...

```
$ git branch -q
* (HEAD detached at c61a6d2)
  master
```

Comment: Are you sure this output is ready for consumption (i.e. text parsing)?

Comment: Sure enough to use it in [my git wrapper](https://github.com/mpenning/git_crazy/blob/63a32ad5a525c2113ab7e0434b8bc8acfdb1c356/gitc.py#L1618).  Could git change output?  Yes, but vulnerabiity to bit-rot is common to any code you write.  If you're worried, write a unit test...