# View NUMBER of local uncommitted files

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I've learned I can use `count` to find the NUMBER of commits a branch is ahead/behind by, like so:

`git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}`

But is there a way to do so for uncommitted files?

Just found out `git status -suno` shows how many files have been changed in a really concise way, so I could either count the lines of the output (with `echo "$var" | wc -l`) or just put a symbol to denote an arbitrary amount exist, or parse it in a weird way to see the number of deleted/added/modified.

However, do non "porcelain" and more directly-addressing commands exist to accomplish this task, as parsing commands such as these are seen as bad practice?

Also, I am using this to add to a git-bash prompt; I would normally just type in git status, but would like to have maximum convenience by just showing such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, the [`--porcelain` option of `git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt) is meant to be parsed:

```
 git status --porcelain -suno|wc -l
```

So while `git status` is porcelain, `git status --porcelain` does produce output suitable for consumption by porcelain scripts.

I tried to explain said option in "[What does the term “porcelain” mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)"

Comment: Interesting (and also kind of annoying)! However, using  `git status --porcelain` gives me an output of `?? newFile.txt` as expected, as I only  ran `touch newFile.txt` before hand, but adding the `-suno` flag changes the output to nothing. I have already written some code to parse `git status -suno`; can I expect porcelain to produce a similar output (displaying two letters, one denoting the working tree, and one denoting the index)?

Comment: @ByNoMeans It will count modified files, meaning their content has been modified. A simple touch would not count in that mode.