# Strange command substitution behaviour in windows git bash

Tags: git-bash

When I use the command substitution operator in `git-bash.exe`, the output does not seem to be correct. For example:

```sh
$ git branch
  master
  one
* two

$ ls
a  b  c

$ echo $(git branch)
master one a b c two
```

As you can see, the output of `$(git branch)` seems to have the files in the current working directory inserted into it.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this isn't specific to git bash.

This is happening because the output of `git branch` has a `"*"` which tells you the branch you are on:

```
$ git branch
* master
  one
  two
```

The star is captured when the command is run

```
> cat file.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

BRANCHES=$(git branch)
```

```
> ./file.sh
++ git branch
+ BRANCHES='* master
  one
  two'
```

then expanded to the files in the working directory.

From [this reference](https://salferrarello.com/git-branch-list-without-asterisk/)

```
> git branch --format='%(refname:short)'
master
one
two
```

you can strip out the star.

I believe we are [advised against using the git porcelain commands for scripting though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/4303355).