# Can git for-each-ref use options set with git-config?

Tags: git, git-config

After

```bash
git config for-each-ref.count 2
```

running

```bash
git for-each-ref refs/heads
```

shows lots of output, while

```bash
git for-each-ref --count=2 refs/heads
```

only shows two, as required.

It seems as if `git for-each-ref` does not use options set with `git-config`. If it does, how can I get it to work?

Comment: `git for-each-ref` is a *plumbing command* and as such, it would be inappropriate for it to have any settings. It's meant to behave the same for every user, when run from scripts that use it, regardless of that user's configuration setting. (What made you expect `git config for-each-ref.count` to do something here?)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about 'plumbing command'.

Comment: Git's notion of plumbing vs porcelain is useful, but Git is not entirely self-consistent here. For instance `git status` is both (!) as it has `--porcelain` and `--porcelain=v2` options. (I still don't get why the "make porcelain command behave as plumbing" option is generally spelled `--porcelain` in Git...)

Comment: BTW I asked the question about expectations in case there's something that can be made clearer in the Git documentation, although in this case I suspect the syntax you suggested was on some bogus web page somewhere...

Comment: No, no bogus web page. I am using magit and wanted it to sort branches on the status page (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70029/12065). I found in its source that it uses `for-each-ref`, read the man page of `for-each-ref` and tried to configure it. I searched for 'config' and 'option' in the page as well as skimmed over `git-config` docs to find a hint as to why `for-each-ref` doesn't care. If anything could be improved, a line like 'this is a plumbing command and does not read the config' would need to be added to each such git command.

Comment: BTW: even if I would have been aware of the distinction between 'plumbing' and 'porcelain', `git config --help` would have told me this: `The configuration variables are used by both the Git plumbing and the porcelains` :-/

Comment: OK - that's exactly the kind of improvement I'm looking for, where someone can clarify the wording in some actual man page included with Git! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a `for-each-ref.count` setting in [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

And I do not see any reference to `count` in [`builtin/for-each-ref.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/for-each-ref.c#L40), except as an *option* (not a git config setting).

Those are the main reasons why `git for-each-ref` (be it [plumbing or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)) would not use that particular (non-existent) option set with `git-config`.