# Git tags moving from one remote branch to another

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-tag

I somehow managed to import git tags from one remote repository to a different one. What I did wrong in the said action sequence and how to avoid importing git tags into different remote git repo in the following scenario?

There are two different code solutions (lets say, A and B) in two seperate gitlab remote projects. Both solutions share some similar code. I did code changes in local branch from project A, commited and pushed them using sourcetree, then copied c# files with changes. Then I added additional remote repository path in sourcetree, and checked out master branch from remote project B, copy pasted c# files only, created commit with those files only, did pull command and then pushed to remote project B master.
Suddenly git tags from remote project A appears in remote project B Gitlab page.

Comment: A tag is attached to a commit. You sent the same commits to the second remote, you sent their tags to the second remote.

Comment: i did not sent same commit to second remote. the changes in files were the same, but they were copy pasted from backup folder outside branch files and new commit was created after second checkout

Comment: Sounds like you might be misreading the output from git. Tags are not namespaced to a remote, and unless you manually push them with `push --tags` or `push <remote> tag-name` they're not pushed or pulled during normal [plumbing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976473/237955) operations. Try cloning from the "tagless" remote to confirm that the tags exist there.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. When i checked out second repo trough SourceTree and run

```
git tag
```

i still got tags from my first repo shown. When doing push on sourceTree, a window opened and on bottom of it was checkbox "push all tags", unchecking it stopped tags from going into remote repo into gitlab.