# How to merge changes from local into a newly pushed code to the remote?

Tags: git, gitlab

Basically I'm working on a program. My partner pushes a code onto Gitlab that works on a different function than me. I've also been working on a different function. He pushes his code to Gitlab with only his new function changed. But my current program on my local machine is of course behind, and I want to basically merge those changes.

1. what is the best way to go about this? Right now I'm just doing "git stash" and then pulling his changes, and then manually putting in my changed code, but I know there's a better way to go about this.
2. let's say also that he changed a singular line of code outside of his function that was at the beginning of the program, e.g., a print statement to print data1, and then I changed this print a different variable called data2. This would create, I'm guessing, a "merge conflict", how do I work with this? Would the most recent push (mine) be given priority or what?

Comment: There is no such thing as "push a code". What did your partner push? A branch? Is it the same branch that you are on?

Comment: @matt Yes, I meant branch, but I just said code because I'm emphasizing one file being changed with that branch (all the input files and everything else staying the same). And yes, we're on the same branch (a feature branch).

Comment: OK well that's a bug. Two people should never be working directly on one and the same branch (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to go about this?

As someone who is more skilled with Git than most, I usually:

1. `stash` or `commit` my changes to my branch
2. `git rebase origin/main`
3. `stash pop` (if I stashed my changes in step 1, no need if you committed them)

This might not work for you all the time, but since I'm so comfortable with `rebase` it's what I do by default. *Mmmmm, linear history.*

Commit often. If you're familiar with `rebase`, you can always go back and edit commits later.

You could also just, you know, *not care*. Don't worry about if your local branch has conflicts with the upstream. That may come up when you open your Merge Request, but it's beyond caring about right now.

Git is really pretty good at dealing with merge conflicts; if the **same line** is inserted in the **same place** in a file in two separate commits, Git will *usually* figure that out during the merge and make sure only one line is inserted.

Code issues caused by non-Git conflicts (e.g. two people add the same method name with different signatures) should be caught by having proper unit tests. They can save time when figuring out what went wrong and when.

### Steps Toward Git Mastery

It sounds like you've learned the basic Git [porcelain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git) commands like push, pull, add, commit, etc. Maybe you know merge. Now you want to further your understanding. Here's a quick sprint through the evolution of my understanding of Git.

First of all, [Git for Ages 4 and Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4) explains how to reason about what Git is doing under the hood. Conceptualize commits, learn to visualize what's going on, and you'll be less confused by how Git works.

A project's commit history is as much a part of the project as the code itself. Once I got used to [browsing the commit history](https://jonas.github.io/tig/), I realized just how true this is. I came to appreciate [well-formatted commit messages](https://cbea.ms/git-commit/).

From there, I learned how to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) my commits to clean them up and organize them. Maybe those commits will even be something you're *proud of*.